# Is it possible to have forceFitColumns and horizontalScrollBar both at the same time

Tags: angular, slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

I have a table that I created using angular-slickgrid AngularGridInstance in that I can add new columns, reorder the columns, shrink and expand the columns

If I expand the columns too much that it goes beyond the screen then a Horizontal scroll bar comes which is fine.

However, when I shrink columns excessively, a gap appears on the right side, which is undesirable. How can I ensure that the last column covers any gap created by shrinking columns?

I tried using forceFitColumns = true. But if I use that then it causes problems when I expand the columns other columns get shrunk and no scroll bar is displauyed. So I was thinking is there any possible way in which I can forceFitColumns and can have Horizontalscroll bar bothe at the same time.

Comment: the short answer is No. When I created Angular-Slickgrid, I never liked what the force fit column does except when initializing the grid. So what I did is call `grid.autosizeColumns()` on grid init which is what force fit does but at all time. You would need to detect when the columns become smaller than the viewport and then call `autosizeColumns()`, there is no code that does that at the moment and I don't plan on adding that. You can contribute a Pull Request if you want. BTW, this is not a coding question, your question might get closed since you didn't provide any code.